# this.setState() not changing value (not an asynchronous update issue)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, state

Just a note, this question is **NOT** an asynchronous update problem (at least, I don't *think* it is).

I have a **class component** with the following content (heavily simplified to get right to the issue):

```
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
       aSelected: false;
       bSelected: false
     }
  }

 handleCheckboxChange = (e) => {   
     const { checked, value } = e.target;
    
     console.log( 'checked: ', checked );

     if(value=="a") {
        this.setState( {aSelected: checked}, () =>  {
        console.log('aSelected: ', this.state.aSelected);
        console.log("---")
     });
     }

     if(value=="b") {
        this.setState( {bSelected: checked}, () =>  {
        console.log('bSelected: ', this.state.bSelected);
        console.log("---")
     });
     } 
 }
```

Somewhere inside the render return, I have this:

```
<input>
   type="checkbox"
   value="a"
   onChange={this.handleCheckboxChange}
   checked={this.state.aSelected}
   disabled={ (this.state.aSelected || (!this.state.aSelected && !this.state.bSelected) ) ? false : true} 
</input>

<input>
   type="checkbox"
   value="b"
   onChange={this.handleCheckboxChange}
   checked={this.state.bSelected}
   disabled={ (this.state.bSelected || (!this.state.aSelected && !this.state.bSelected) ) ? false : true}
</input>
```

Here is the output logged in Chrome Developer Tools. As you can see, "checked" is toggled appropriately each time I selected and unselect the checkbox. However, the state of "selected" (should say "aSelected") is never changed and always has the initial state value of false. Anyone know why the value of "selected" (should say "aSelected") is never changed?

Edit: My goal is to create two checkbox items, where the user can only select ONE or select NONE. While one is selected, the other should be **disabled**.

[image]

Comment: Please refer this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58486512/how-to-change-props-value-in-react-js

Comment: The `input` element doesn't seem to use the `selected` property from your component state

Comment: @siddmuk2005 I am not asking about changing the props value.

Comment: @byxor I only provided what was relevant to the question. I am asking about the logged output "selected" not matching with the toggling "checked" value.

Comment: @penguin I know

Comment: @byxor I have added more code to provide clarification on how I'm using selected (now "aSelected" and "bSelected") in the input element

Comment: `disabled={!aSelected}` `disabled={!bSelected}` will cause each input element to use the state from your component. Could be something funky going on with your boolean logic there, not 100% sure. Also not 100% sure if `disabled` is the right attribute (on the input element) for achieving this. Someone else can fill in the details

Answer (score 3):

When you call `setState` to update the state, React re-renders the component, which resets the checkbox back to it's default (i.e. unchecked) state.

You'll need to use the current state to manage the checkbox as well. The JSX should look something like:

```
<input
   type="checkbox"
   checked={this.state.aSelected}
   onChange={this.handleCheckboxChange}
/>
```

In React's terms, this is what's known as a "controlled component" because React is fully responsible for keeping up with the input's state. Read more in the docs here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components
vs
https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html

**Edit to match the question's edits**:
In your render function, be sure you're using `this.state.aSlected`. Note, you also still need the `checked={this.state.aChecked}` attribute as well, otherwise the checkbox will be unchecked on the next render.
Like:

```
<input
   type="checkbox"
   value="a"
   onChange={this.handleCheckboxChange}
   checked={this.state.aSelected}
   // added for clarification *
   disabled={this.state.aSelected || (!this.state.aSelected && !this.state.bSelected) ? false : true} 
/>
```

**Edit with Working Example**
Here's [a working CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-allen-z9xtc?file=/src/CheckboxComponent.js:50-1204) where checking one checkbox disables the other:

```
class CheckboxComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      aSelected: false,
      bSelected: false
    };
  }

  handleCheckbox = (event) => {
    if (event.target.name === "boxA") {
      this.setState({ aSelected: event.target.checked });
    } else if (event.target.name === "boxB") {
      this.setState({ bSelected: event.target.checked });
    }
  };

  render() {
    let aDisabled = this.state.bSelected && !this.state.aSelected;
    let bDisabled = this.state.aSelected && !this.state.bSelected;

    return (
      <div>
        <label>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            name="boxA"
            checked={this.state.aSelected}
            onChange={this.handleCheckbox}
            disabled={aDisabled}
          />
          Checkbox A
        </label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <label>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            name="boxB"
            checked={this.state.bSelected}
            onChange={this.handleCheckbox}
            disabled={bDisabled}
          />
          Checkbox B
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what this means. If I select multiple checkboxes, input on UI and somewhere internally setState is called the whole UI input elements will reset ?

Comment: Thanks for your input, @Jeremy. However, I am still not getting a toggled "selected" value.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my code in the question to clarify how I'm using selected (now "aSelected" and "bSelected") in the input element.

Comment: @penguin I've updated my answer as well.

Comment: When I do as you say, the "checked" var that I've logged always returns true.

Comment: @penguin I've made another edit to add a CodeSandbox exmaple. Hope that helps!